# Default export error even after exporting the component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation bar using react-bootstrap by referring to their [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbar-brand-props).

I created a NavigationBar.js component file which I'll import.

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const NavigationBar = props => {
  const { link, brand } = props;
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" sticky="top">
      <Navbar.brand href={link}>{brand}</Navbar.brand>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

NavigationBar.propTypes = {
  brand: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  link: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default NavigationBar;
```

And my App.js (where I am importing the component):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavigationBar brand="xyz" link="#home" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code compiles fine but throws an error in the browser as follows:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `NavigationBar`.
```

What can be done to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error comes from this line

```
      <Navbar.brand href={link}>{brand}</Navbar.brand>
```

The names of the components in react have to start with capital letter. This means that the Navbar.brand should be Navbar.Brand